# Define virtualenv and linter executables relative to sublime-project in sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, virtualenv

I am trying to figure out what the best set-up for working with sublime text 3 and python virtual environments is.

I am using the Virtualenv package and my typical project structure consists of a root directory including a virtual environment always called *venv*, located in the root folder of my projects. In order to access the virtualenv I have to specify the location of *venv* on a per-project base in the sublime-project file and set the *virtualenv* entry. I also have to specify the absolute paths to all linters I am using.

It's not a big deal, but it certainly is tedious to set these entries every time I'm playing around on a new small project.

I hoped there would be a smooth solution, in which the Virtualenv package automatically detects the nearest *venv* and linter executables.

Something like a default sublime-project file which would take relative values for all commonly used paths.

I tried fiddling around but have not managed to get something but hardcoding paths to work.

I feel like this is a common problem, so I think there must be an easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue myself and in case anyone is interested this is what I ended up doing:

First of all, apparently I'm not the only one with this issue ([here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-eslint/issues/135), [here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/366), [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/home-variable-in-project-config/30262), and [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/variable-for-home-directory/10568), which all seem to share similar problems) but it took me some digging to finally find an easy answer that works for me.

To re-iterate, my problem was finding an easy way around hardwiring paths to virtual environments and linter executables for every little project I had, without needing to do any global installs.

- In the case of the virtual environment the need to do any configuration in a sublime-project file is avoided by simply using package control to locate the desired *venv* in the projects root folder (Ctrl + Shift + P -> VirtualEnv: Activate). This directory is automatically added to the sublime-project file, and by choosing the *python + virtualenv* build system is automatically invoked in future builds, disregarding whether the venv is actually activated or not. Obvioulsy, the [*Virtualenv*](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Virtualenv) package has to be installed for this to work.
- Furthermore, in order to not have to redefine linter executables over and over again, the [SublimeLinter Documentation](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/stable/settings.html#settings-expansion) states that SublimeTexts *expand_variables* *API* may be invoked to access a bunch of predefined variables as well as all environment variables by using the `${variable_name}` syntax. However, what the documentation does not say - and what apparently prevented many others from actually resolving their issues - is that variable expansion does not work in the *SublimeLinter.paths* property as *kaste* points out in [this thread](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter/issues/1525). So, variable expansion *does* work, it just has to directly target linter executables. In my case I'm using pythons pyflake and pycodestyle and my SublimeLinter user settings now look like this

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{

***

    // Provide extra paths to be searched when locating system executables.
    "paths": {
        "linux": [],
        "osx": [],
        "windows": [],
    },

    "linters": {
        "pycodestyle": {
            "executable": "${project_path}\\venv\\Scripts\\pycodestyle.exe",
        },
        "pyflakes": {
            "executable": "${project_path}\\venv\\Scripts\\pyflakes.exe",
        }
    },
}
```

where I am accessing the *project_path* variable to create the full path to the executable from there. This only requires that I follow a consistent convention of naming my virtual environment *venv* and placing them in the same directory as my sublime-project file and installing any linters I might use directly into the projects virtual environment.

One of the advantages of this setup is that it works for both python2 and python3 and lints the code correctly depending on the version used for the venv without requiring any more set-up.

Lots of text for such a little tweak, but maybe someone else starting on sublime might find this useful.

Comment: A major "thank you" for writing this out. I read multiple other SO posts and was unable to get their solutions to work for me in ST3 with a virtualenv. Just one thing I wasn't able to follow: how did you set the SublimeLinter settings for each project independently? Do I have to start a separate venv and launch ST3 from terminal beforehand?

Comment: The SublimeLinter settings are set independently from the project settings in preferences -> Package Settings. This particular setup requires that for each of your  projects, a virtualenv called _venv_ has to be created. Then you have to create a _sublime project_ and save it to the same folder the _venv_ lives in. This way ST always finds the corresponding _venv_ for each project, because they are named identically and their path is determined from the save location of the sublime project. No need to use terminal once this is done, but you have to use a separate venv for each project.